# Recreating a letterhead

Tags: line-spacing, letterhead

I am using a [.cls template](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) to generate a letterhead for my resume, by the following snippet:

```
\def\namefont{\huge\bf}
\def\@linename{\begingroup
  \def\\{, }
  {\namefont\@name}
  \vskip 2pt
  \fullline
  \vskip 2pt
  % where do you live?
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{%
    % do nothing
  }{%
    \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth
      {\hfill\vbox{\hbox{\@addressone}
           \hbox{\@addresstwo}
          }%
      }\par
  }
\endgroup}
```

I need to recreate this for a different document, and I have done so like this:

```
\begin{flushleft}
  \huge\bfseries Name
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\end{flushleft}
\medskip\hrule height 0.5pt
\begin{flushright}
  address1 \\
  address2 
\end{flushright}
```

In the second version, there is a space between the huge name and the vertical line which I'd like to remove. Also the vertical line is black and not grey... How can I match the first version?

Note: This is only my second project in LaTeX.

Comment: Regarding the vertical space, you should remove `\medskip`. If that doesn't please you, add a negative space manually with `\vskip-10pt`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `\medskip` to get rid of the extra vertical space. For the color, use the package `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
  \huge\bfseries Name
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\end{flushleft}
{\color{gray}\hrule height 0.5pt}
\begin{flushright}
  address1 \\
  address2
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```